# :first-child selector not applying in emotion css

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors

I have a styled component as below

```
const StyledCustomComponent = styled.aside`
min-width: ${gridPts(19)};
background-color: ${HIGHLIGHT_BLUE};
flex: 0 0 auto;
${fontSize(13)}
padding: ${gridPts(2)};

@media only screen and (max-width: ${MQ_320}) {
padding: ${gridPts(1)};
}

@media only screen and (min-width: ${MQ_1285}), (min-width: ${MQ_575}) and (max-width: ${MQ_961}) {

  &:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
`
```

When I inspect it in the browser and resize to match the media query, the :first-child style does not apply.

And the child components of the above component are styled as below

```
const StyledCustomComponentChild = css`
  margin: ${gridPts(1)} ${gridPts(1)} 0;
  @media only screen and (max-width: ${MQ_575}), (min-width: ${MQ_961}) and (max-width: ${MQ_1285}) {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      margin-right: ${gridPts(1)};

      & * {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: ${gridPts(1)};
      }
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: ${MQ_1285}), (min-width: ${MQ_575}) and (max-width: ${MQ_961}) {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: ${gridPts(3)} 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
     &:first-child {
      display: block;
    }
  }
`
```

This style is applied to the component itself instead of its first child

here is the screen shot of how the style is interpreted in the browser dev tools

[image]

Notice there is no `space` before `:first-child`
If I manually add a space through dev tools then the style is applied as expected

```js
import styled from 'react-emotion'

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
 color: turquoise;
& :last-child {   
 color:green;
  }
 & :first-child {
  color: red;
 }
 
`
render(
 <StyledDiv>
<p>First</p>
<p>Second</p>
<p>third</p>
<p>last</p>
 </StyledDiv>
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone guess what might be the issue?

Comment: Add a code sample we can run, we will then be able to help

Comment: I think the root element is not a first child to its parent.

Answer (score 3):

Both selectors work for me. Use a tag like `<div/>` or `<p/>` etc. before :last-child (depending on your code, it may be also another tag).

```
export const blogSection = css`
  display:flex;
  & div:last-child {
  background: #ff0000;
  }
`;
```